# Play video file with broken AVI index on iOS using MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, vlc

I'm working on a video streaming app for iOS, and I faced up with a problem - the app should be able to play partially downloaded videos. I can't stream video directly from a server because there is no server, videos are downloaded using P2P network. Download starts from the beginning of the file and after about 20% I want to be able to play the file.

Currently I'm trying to use `MobileVLCKit`. When I try to play a partially downloaded file (about 30%) using VLC player on my Mac, VLC tells me: "*Broken or missing AVI Index*" and offers to "*Play as is*" or "*Build index and than play*", when I choose "*Play as is*" video starts playing, but on iOS when I try to play the same video I get `BAD_ACCESS` when `MobileVLCKit` invoke `AVI_IndexCreate`. Is there a way to force `MobileVLCKit` to play video "as is" with a broken index, or maybe there are some other options how I can to this? Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

console output:

```
[1389:617849] creating player instance using shared library
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-color does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-opacity does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-position does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-refresh does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-size does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-timeout does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-x does not exist
[1759f504] core generic error: option marq-y does not exist
[176f8264] avi demux error: no key frame set for track 0
[176f8264] avi demux error: no key frame set for track 1
```

backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #8: tid = 0x976f9, 0x20000000, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20000000)
    frame #0: 0x20000000
  * frame #1: 0x00675d72 testApp'Open [inlined] AVI_IndexCreate + 542 at avi.c:2407
    frame #2: 0x00675b54 testApp'Open(p_this=<unavailable>) + 5228 at avi.c:631
    frame #3: 0x0065111e testApp'vlc_module_load [inlined] module_load(obj=<unavailable>, init=<unavailable>, args=0x04d29d94, args=0x04d29d94, args=<unavailable>) + 814 at modules.c:185
    frame #4: 0x00651100 testApp'vlc_module_load(obj=0x155f7654, capability=0x008fdd2e, name=<unavailable>, strict=false, probe=<unavailable>) + 784 at modules.c:277
    frame #5: 0x0065129a testApp'module_need(obj=<unavailable>, cap=<unavailable>, name=<unavailable>, strict=<unavailable>) + 30 at modules.c:366
    frame #6: 0x0062ae9a testApp'demux_New + 734
    frame #7: 0x00634a4c testApp'InputSourceInit + 2624
    frame #8: 0x00631e74 testApp'Init + 580
    frame #9: 0x00633c7a testApp'Run + 18
    frame #10: 0x35542e92 libsystem_pthread.dylib'_pthread_body + 138
    frame #11: 0x35542e06 libsystem_pthread.dylib'_pthread_start + 118
```

Comment: Please add a backtrace to your question so we can see where it crashes. This is expected to work just the way you describe it from the Mac.

Comment: Added backtrace and console. Also I forgot to mention that I'm using latest  version of MobileVLCKit available through CocoaPods. In the podspec it is market as version 2.2.1, but it use the sources from here http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc-iOS/2.3.0/MobileVLCKit-2.2.0-rc1-binary.zip , so I don't know which version number is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default VLCKit tries to repair broken AVI index, to disable this behaviour you need to pass `--avi-index=2` param to a player. On iOS you can do it on init, like this:

`VLCMediaPlayer *player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[@"--avi-index=2"]];`